# Custom Binding initialisation

Tags: swiftui

I want control the passed value to Binding for custom initializing, I am using this down code, xcode throw me this:

[image]

need help to solve the problem, thanks for help.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var int: Int = Int()
    
    var body: some View {

        BindingView(int: $int)
        
    }
}


struct BindingView: View {
    
    @Binding var int: Int
    
    init(int: Binding<Int>) {
        
        if int == 0 {               // <<:  Here
            
            _int = 100              // <<:  Here
            
        }
        else {
            
            _int = int

        }

    }

    var body: some View {
        
        Text(int.description)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `Int` directly like that for comparison, since it's a @Binding.  Instead, you'll want to access its `wrappedValue`:

You're also running into a couple funny things just from naming your input parameter (`int`) the same as your stored property, but it's easily fixable.  Here's one variation:

```
struct BindingView: View {
    
    @Binding var int: Int
    
    init(int: Binding<Int>) {
        
        if int.wrappedValue == 0 {               // <<:  Here
            
            int.wrappedValue = 100              // <<:  Here
            
        }
        
        self._int = int

    }

    var body: some View {
        
        Text(int.description)

    }
}
```

*Note that there's some tricky subtlety here: `@Binding` lets you directly access the underlying value, while with `Binding<Int>` you have to use the `wrappedValue` property.*

Comment: What if I use _int = .constant(100) instead of  int.wrappedValue = 100 ???

Comment: Then it will no longer function as a Binding — it will be a constant at that point

Comment: So, I guess the question is: do you really need a binding, or just a regular property

Comment: I think I asked my question in comment in bad way, I what ask you this:                         if int.wrappedValue == 0 {               
            
            _int = .constant(100)
            
        }
        else {
            
            _int = int

        }

Comment: You certainly could. Depends on what your goal is.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, my last question, we can use or not use "self." in the codes we discussed, for example: ** self._int = int or _int = int   ** xcode would not complain about missing self if we do not use it, would you prefer to use it like old faction way of initializing properties or like me just omit the self, I know it does not make deference in result but would you omit it? or would you used it like old way.

Comment: In general, I personally try to avoid using custom inits for my structure in general. In this case, I opted to use self to further differentiate between the input parameter and the stored property.